# Adding folders to the eSpace Tree

Tags: outsystems

I'm building a website in OutSystems.
For this website I use a custom font.
Is it possible to add a folder to the eSpace Tree so I can put my custom font in that folder?

Or is there another way to add the custom font to the espace?

Grtz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the font as a resource. Make sure that the resource has the deploy action defined as 'Deploy to Target Directory'.

Then, you can refer to it in the css with the path

```
/eSpaceName/fontname.ttf
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the deploy action. Without setting the deploy action the resource is not reachable.